# UITableView in landscape larger than screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I have an `UITableView` in an `UINavigationController` that is the master in a `UISplitViewController`.
My problem is in `Portrait` everything is fine but in landscape my table is larger than the screen that means I can scroll further than my screen is...

EDIT:
My `UISplitViewController` is in an `UITabbarController`, when I start in Portrait everything works it doesn't work if I start in landscape mode.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, please check my answer as correct.

Comment: not really, its some kind of strange problem with combination of uisplitview and uitabcontroller

Comment: If you have found a solution, maybe you want to post it. It can be useful for others.

Comment: I do it when I found a real solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with a `UISplitViewController` in a `UITabBarController`.
I help me now in this way that I manually change the size of my view frame to the needed one in viewdidappear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `autoresizingMask` to your tableview in `viewDidLoad:` method

```
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

You table will be resized automatically